# Asynchronous method call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I tried to make an asynchronous call.
I am not sure about the following question:
We tend to say an asynchronous method call returns immediately. Is that true?
Someone said it is not true.
Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could post the actual code involved.

Comment: The async call doesn't block the next line of code from running, so when you make the call, the code execution continues on without waiting for that call to complete. Was there some specific issue you're having?

Comment: It may not seem like it on the face of it, but the answers to the linked dupetarget answer your question, too. (Which is SO's definition of a duplicate question, which may not match the definition one might expect.)